# Creating NuGet Packages - Why doesn't this folder structure work for .NET 4.0?

Tags: .net-4.0, nuget, nuget-package

Here is the issue I'm having - I cannot get my project's NuGet package to work for .NET 4.0.

Here is what my folder structure looks like:

```
 lib\   
      \.NET 4.0
          binary.dll   
      \Silverlight 4.0
          binary.silverlight.dll
```

Whenever I try to add this package to a Silverlight 4 project, it works just fine. When I try to add it to an ASP.NET MVC3 app I get the following error: "unable to find assembly references that are compatible with the target framework '.NETFramework, version=v4.0'"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: .NET Framework = `net`. Silverlight = `sl`. .NETMicroFramework = `netmf`. So .NET Framework 3.5 would be `net35`.

Comment: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Framework_Names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the folder name to Net40 and SL4 (or Silverlight4 no spaces). You should file a bug though, those names should work. I think the "." in .NET might be throwing it off.

Comment: Is the best place to add a bug report on the CodePlex project for NuGet?

Comment: Also, that worked by the way - my new package is now working properly on NuGet